# Evaluate sin(arctan(12/13)) and provide your answer as a fraction

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

So far all the questions have used special triangles so I've found arctan using the corresponding special triangle, then found sin using that angle. But for this question it doesn't seem to use a special triangle so I'm unsure as to how I can provide my answer as a fraction. Thank you for any help I appreciate it.

Comment: I'm slightly suspicious because 12, 13, and 7 form a Pythagorean triple. If you were asked for 
$$\tan( \sin^{-1}(\frac{12}{13}))$$
the answer would be $\frac{12}7$, it just seems the kind of question that is often asked, where the answer comes out nicely as a fraction.

Comment: @WW1:  Did you mean $12, 13, $ and $\color{red}5$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a right triangle with base length $13$ and height $12$. Its hypotenuse length is $\sqrt{169+144}=\sqrt{313}$.

The base angle is $\arctan(12/13)$. Sine of that angle is $\frac{12}{\sqrt{313}}$.

Answer (score 3):

It is easiest for problems like these to draw a right triangle. Since you have an $\arctan(12/13)$, you want to consider an angle in your right triangle, such that the opposite side has a length of $12$, and the adjacent a length of $13$. Drawing the diagram, where the angle you desire is $x$,

[image]

Since $x = \arctan(12/13)$, now you just want $\sin(x)$, which you can find by using the definition of sine and the Pythagorean theorem.

Answer (score 0):

$$y=\sin\left(\arctan(x)\right)=\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$$ So, for your case $y=\frac{12}{\sqrt{313}}$.

If you need to express the result as a fraction of whole numbers, you need to rationalize the result. You would get the sequence
$$\left\{\frac{2}{3},\frac{11}{16},\frac{19}{28},\frac{78}{115},\frac{253}{373},\frac
   {584}{861},\frac{3076}{4535},\frac{4906}{7233},\frac{28521}{42049},\frac{81572}{
   120263}\right\}$$

Have a look [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=rationalize%5B12%2Fsqrt%5B313%5D%2C10%5E%28-n%29%5D+for+n%3D1+to+10).